# How do i get a field of the last inserted row?

Tags: mysql

Using mysql:
I am inserting a row into a table with one auto_increment field left as null (so that gets auto-filled). How would i go about getting the auto incrementing field in  a new query that happens right after the insert?

Example:
`INSERT INTO Food VALUES (1, "pizza");`
?
`SELECT * FROM Food WHERE ?` (Get the last inserted row)

Just looking for "pizza" won't work in my case as the only unique field is the auto incrementing one.

I also don't want to just select and order by because of race conditions (these inserts happen asynchronously.)

Comment: Please tag your MySQL version.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [LAST_INSERT_ID()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id).

<sub>Quoted from docs:</sub>

**LAST_INSERT_ID(), LAST_INSERT_ID(expr)**

> With no argument, `LAST_INSERT_ID()` returns a `BIGINT UNSIGNED` (64-bit) value representing the first automatically generated value successfully inserted for an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column as a result of **the most recently executed `INSERT` statement**. The value of `LAST_INSERT_ID()` remains unchanged if no rows are successfully inserted.
>
> With an argument, `LAST_INSERT_ID()` returns an unsigned integer.
>
> ```
> SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
> ```

You can find an extended example in this chapter:

[28.7.29.3 How to Get the Unique ID for the Last Inserted Row](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/getting-unique-id.html)

```
CREATE TABLE T
(
    ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    FOO INT
);

INSERT INTO T (FOO) VALUES (100);
INSERT INTO T (FOO) VALUES (200);
INSERT INTO T (FOO) VALUES (300);

SELECT * FROM T WHERE ID = LAST_INSERT_ID();

ID | FOO
-: | --:
 3 | 300
```

Let me add the advice [Akina](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/150107/akina) has pointed out in comments:

> There is a problem. LAST_INSERT_ID() scope is connection. If connection pool used or reconnection occured, zero will be returned. One of the solutions is to execute all queries within stored procedure.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d39ccd0ddc88babe33672a72563b8563)*

Comment: There is a problem. LAST_INSERT_ID() scope is connection. If connection pool used or reconnection occured, zero will be returned. One of the solutions is to execute all queries within stored procedure.

Comment: @Akina thanks, I've added it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't delete any of the rows in your table, this should work :

```
SELECT * FROM Food WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM Food) ;
```

Comment: Nice, grammar correction: `in case you don't delete any...`

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Could you detail some of these use cases please? I only see the one in which you delete rows.

Comment: *inserts happen asynchronously* - so it's possible that between 1st and 2nd inserts more records will be inserted.