# How to use the id of the new generated row in the consecutive queries in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

```
# Copy Row

INSERT INTO dashboards
    (title, description)
SELECT 
    title, description
FROM 
    dashboards
WHERE 
    id = 111;
```

This first command copies a row that has the id of 111
I want to use the `id` of the newly generated row in the following query

```
# Copy Row2

INSERT INTO another_table
    (dashboard_id, slice_id)
SELECT 
    111, slice_id
FROM 
    another_table
WHERE 
    dashboard_id =<new_id>;
```

So, without having to run these two separately, I want to use the id of the newly generated row as `<new_id>` in the second query.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried thus far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do i get a field of the last inserted row?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/230743/how-do-i-get-a-field-of-the-last-inserted-row)

Answer (score 0):

What is your client language?  The API to MySQL will have a function with a name something like `LAST_INSERT_ID()`  That is used after doing the first `INSERT` to get the Auto_increment id from it so you can use it in the next Insert (or an Update).

Answer (score 0):

You can use LAST_INSERT_ID() in an SQL expression. It returns the auto-increment id generated by the most recent INSERT on the same connection.

```
# Copy Row2

INSERT INTO another_table
    (dashboard_id, slice_id)
SELECT 
    111, slice_id
FROM 
    another_table
WHERE 
    dashboard_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

If you need to use it several times, or if you need to do some other INSERT statements before this one, it may be useful to save it to a user-defined variable.

```
SET @d = LAST_INSERT_ID();

...

# Copy Row2

INSERT INTO another_table
    (dashboard_id, slice_id)
SELECT 
    111, slice_id
FROM 
    another_table
WHERE 
    dashboard_id = @d;
```